# Class decorator in Python to set variables for the constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, meta-programming

I personally don't like the boilerplate of most `__init__` methods:

```
self.a = a
self.b = b
...
```

So I thought this would be a nice opportunity to learn a bit more about decorators. As this is my first attempt on a class decorator I'm sure there is a lot to improve so fire away:

**Implementation**

```
from collections import namedtuple

def autofill(*args, **kwargs):
    """ This class decorator declares all attributes given into the constructor
    followed by a call of __init__ without arguments (beside reference to self).
    Order is the same than namedtuple with the possibility of default elements.
    Note that in this decorator alters the existing class instance instead of
    returning a wrapper object. """


    def filler(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """ This is our custom initialization method. Input sanitation and
        ordering is outsourced to namedtuple. """

        for key, val in InputSanitizer(*args, **kwargs)._asdict().items():
            setattr(cls, key, val)

        filler.super_init(cls)


    def init_switcher(cls):
        filler.super_init = cls.__init__
        cls.__init__ = filler
        return cls


    # Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351032/named-tuple-and-
    # optional-keyword-arguments
    InputSanitizer = namedtuple('InputSanitizer', args + tuple(kwargs.keys()))
    InputSanitizer.__new__.__defaults__ = tuple(kwargs.values())

    return init_switcher
```

**Some test cases**

```
import unittest

class TestAutoFill(unittest.TestCase):
    @autofill('a', b=12)
    class Foo(dict):
        pass


    def test_zero_input(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            self.Foo()


    def test_one_input(self):
        bar = self.Foo(1)
        self.assertEqual(bar.a, 1)
        self.assertEqual(bar.b, 12)

        bar = self.Foo(a=1)
        self.assertEqual(bar.a, 1)
        self.assertEqual(bar.b, 12)

        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            self.Foo(b=1)

        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            self.Foo(c=12)


    def test_two_input(self):
        bar = self.Foo(1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(bar.a, 1)
        self.assertEqual(bar.b, 2)

        bar = self.Foo(b=2, a=1)
        self.assertEqual(bar.b, 2)
        self.assertEqual(bar.a, 1)


    def test_other_object_functions(self):
        bar = self.Foo(1)
        bar.c = 3
        bar['key'] = 4

        self.assertEqual(bar.a, 1)
        self.assertEqual(bar.b, 12)
        self.assertEqual(bar.c, 3)
        self.assertEqual(bar['key'], 4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The parameters to `autofill` could have better names: `args` gives the *argument names* to the constructor, and `kwargs` gives the *keyword names and their default values*, so perhaps `argnames` and `defaults` would be better. This will also help to distinguish them from the parameters to the `filler` function.
2. The function `filler` is used to implement the `__init__` method, so its first argument should be named `self`, not `cls`.
3. The original `__init__` method is recorded in the `super_init` property of the `filler` function. I think that's needlessly tricky. It would be simpler to record it in a local variable:

   ```
   def init_switcher(cls):
       original_init = cls.__init__

       def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
           for k, v in InputSanitizer(*args, **kwargs)._asdict().items():
               setattr(self, k, v)
           original_init(self)

       cls.__init__ = init
       return cls
   ```
4. The implementation mechanism is quite ingenious! It would not have occurred to me to delegate the argument processing to [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). However, I think that it is clearer to delegate it to [`inspect.Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature):

   ```
   from inspect import Parameter, Signature

   def autofill(*argnames, **defaults):
       """Class decorator that replaces the __init__ function with one that
       sets instance attributes with the specified argument names and
       default values. The original __init__ is called with no arguments
       after the instance attributes have been assigned. For example:

       >>> @autofill('a', 'b', c=3)
       ... class Foo: pass
       >>> sorted(Foo(1, 2).__dict__.items())
       [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

       """
       def init_switcher(cls):
           kind = Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD
           signature = Signature(
               [Parameter(a, kind) for a in argnames]
               + [Parameter(k, kind, default=v) for k, v in defaults.items()])
           original_init = cls.__init__

           def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
               bound = signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
               bound.apply_defaults()
               for k, v in bound.arguments.items():
                   setattr(self, k, v)
               original_init(self)

           cls.__init__ = init
           return cls
       return init_switcher
   ```
5. There's no test case that checks that the original `__init__` method is called.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough analysis. I completely agree with almost all the points and have to say I never heard of the `inspect` module before. I guess I'm in for a read... On point 3. I prefer the flatter structure (not 3 level of nested) but otherwise completely agree.